# UI files doesn't show its widgets to gtk_builder_get_objects

Tags: c, gtk, glade, gtkbuilder

I have this UI file edited with Glade 3.18.3. I open the UI in the (C) gtk program (no problem here, no error messages).

Then I tried to get the widget references out of the builder object using `gtk_builder_get_object`, but could not find any.

I read that gtkbuilder used to set the `name` attribute of the widgets to the `id`, but doesn't do that anymore. So I defined the `name` in a couple of widgets, but that didn't help.

In desesperation, I added a simple loop which calls `gtk_builder_get_objects`, but this function returns NULL:

```
  GSList *lp, *lst = gtk_builder_get_objects(builder);

  printf("%p\n", lst);
  for (lp = lst; lp != NULL; lp = lp->next) {
    printf("%s\n", (char *)(lp->data));
  }
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Your example is misleading: you probably have some other problem that your code is not showing.

The following test case uses your very same loop and does not return `NULL`. The ui file does not have any `name` set on the objects. Try it.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main()
{
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GSList *lp, *lst;

    gtk_init(NULL, NULL);

    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("test.ui");
    lst = gtk_builder_get_objects(builder);

    g_print("%p\n", lst);
    for (lp = lst; lp != NULL; lp = lp->next) {
        g_print("%p\n", (char *)(lp->data));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And this is `test.ui`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.24"/>
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkVBox" id="vbox1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">label</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `name` property of the window containing the widgets must *also* be set in the UI, else the `gtk_builder_add_objects_from_file` won't work either.

This is going to be a major headache. The UI is quite complicated (a couple of hundreds of widgets). So that means I have to visit them all in Glade to edit their `name`... or maybe write a script. And this worked so well before.